# Twitter Bootstrap: Sidebar Nav Maintenance

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I apologize in advance if this is a foolish question, but I'm new to Bootstrap and UI design in general.

That being said, my question is around the maintenance of a left nav. Let's say my nav lists four links ... for me that would be four separate source HTML files ... each with their own copy of the nav. So if I add a fifth page to my site I have to edit five files (the original four to update the nav + the new page).

In the searching I've done it seems there's really no good way to have HTML fragments (as well as I'd like this content to run outside of a webserver/appserver). Furthermore, my real scenario is probably closer to 15 pages so the idea of just making it one big file and then using jquery to show/hide the link's content is probably not an option. Is there any component in Bootstrap which would help with that? Or any tool in general?

I've given some thought to just writing a pre-processor which generates the site, but I'm all for using the wheels that others have invented first!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to include HTML code or fragments from other files within an HTML document (yet). This is the one downfall to HTML and makes it difficult to keep all data the same across all pages. The best way I have found doing it is either load all pages via AJAX in one page (for example, when a button is clicked, an html file is loaded into the main content section) or by using PHP to have one main index file that includes content based on `$_GET['']` variables.

It's a bit of a crappy situation seeing as Bootstrap is like a "kill 2 birds with one stone" type of framework, but it's mostly static.

Comment: thanks! i carpool with a guy who gave me another option of using jquery to assemble the page on the fly. he said it could be done still with multiple files and then dynamically reaching in for the right content divs as the page loads (i'd have just one div for each of my navs, of course). while it's far from a great solution, i think it's also usable as it doesn't violate my "one huge file" restriction.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right, you would be re-inventing the wheel to build your own pre-processor, as there's a handful of things that do this very well already.  Of course this can be done in full content-management platforms like wordpress, or by writing your own PHP, etc.

You might want to start by checking out [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), a ruby-based preprocessor which assembles a site.  It uses [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) to create the templates (you could use pure Liquid without Jekyll too).  On every page that needs a navbar, you just add

```
{% include navbar %}
```

and then have a little html fragment that describes your navbar.  Then you need only edit the html in one place.  Jekyll has an active community, and [Jekyll-bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) is probably an easy way to learn to get started with Jekyll, particularly if you already know/plan to use twitter-bootstrap.

There are lots of other similar projects, others you might look at are [ruhoh](http://ruhoh.com/) and [yst](https://github.com/jgm/yst)

Comment: thanks for the notes. both answers are of outstanding quality, so i'm going with the chronology tie breaker. thanks!